# Cordova build fails due to facebook plugin after updating Ionic2 CLI to Ionic3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

Recently I have updated the Ionic2 CLI to Ionic3 CLI but I am facing issue to make a build.

This is happed due to [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook) not putting proper entries resources values file.

Error as like on console as follows:

```
      :app:processDebugResources

      AndroidManifest.xml:68: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka com.myapp.ionic3:string/fb_app_id) not found.

      AndroidManifest.xml:71: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka com.myapp.ionic3:string/fb_app_name) not found.

      error: failed processing manifest.
```

System Information as like as follows:

```
        ionic --version
        3.19.1

        cordova --version
        8.0.0

        node --version
        v9.4.0

        npm --version
        5.6.0

        gradle --version

        ------------------------------------------------------------
        Gradle 4.4.1
        ------------------------------------------------------------

        Build time:   2017-12-20 15:45:23 UTC
        Revision:     10ed9dc355dc39f6307cc98fbd8cea314bdd381c

        Groovy:       2.4.12
        Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
        JVM:          1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14)
        OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.2 x86_64
```

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add this to the config.xml file

```
<platform name="android">
<config-file parent="/resources" target="./res/values/strings.xml">
    <string name="fb_app_id">1234</string>
    <string name="fb_app_name">foobar</string>
</config-file>
...
```

I was having the same problem and it helped me

Comment: thank you so much. I spent 2 days around this and couldn't figure out why my build was failing. 
Now, although my issue is resolved and 'login with fb' is running like manic :) but can you please explain why we had to do this because I already had this in my config.xml 
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^2.2.0">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="111111111111" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="test-app" />
    </plugin>

Comment: @Junaid I'm glad it helped you. To answer your question.. this is a requirement for cordova-android >= 7. See documentation: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/android/README.md#cordova-android--7

Answer (score 6):

Add string resources into strings.xml file :

ie
/path/IonicProject/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

```
    <string name="fb_app_id">232342323</string>
    <string name="fb_app_name">TESTAPP</string>
```

where 232342323 is facebook app id and TESTAPP is appname on faceboook

Answer (score -1):

add yourapp_id in "ionic.config.json"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iue3X.png)

update varable config.xml

```
    <variable name="fb_app_id" value="18914XXXXXX683" />
    <variable name="fb_app_name" value="JXXi" />
```